# How to refer to a specific decade?

Tags: translation

For example, in English we often to the time period 1990-1999 as *the nineties*.

> There was good music in the nineties.

How do you do that in Esperanto? Is there anything short like *the nineties*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think people usually say *la 90aj jaroj* which is pronouced *la naŭdekaj jaroj*. So your example would be:

> Estis bona muziko en la 90aj jaroj.

Here is an example quote from the blog [Egalecen](https://egalecen.org/2017/07/03/genro-kaj-sekso-teoriaj-aliroj/):

> Mal/konstruismo mem konsistas el pluraj skoloj, kiuj estis plej influaj en **la 80aj kaj 90aj jaroj** de la 20a jarcento

To talk about decades from this century you could say for example *la 2010aj jaroj*, (pronounced *la du-mil-dekaj jaroj*). Here is an example from [a book by Renato Corsetti](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/692678):

> En la nuna tempo, **la 2010-aj jaroj**, la angla havas havas grandan influon al la sveda lingvo

Comment: Yes. Just google the following and you will see a lot of examples in recent articles: "aj jaroj" site:www.monato.net